# CDF Player portable

Tags: cdf-format, cdfplayer

Is there a version of CDF player that does not require installation with administrative rights? The exe file that can be downloaded from Wolfram site can only be installed with administrative privileges. A portable version would be much appreciated. As far as I understand the whole concept of CDF is that one should be able to run it anywhere without Mathematica, but the fact that a normal user cannot install it or that it actually requires installation itself breaks this concept.

Comment: Installing the CDF player requires administrative privileges. I would expect it to since it is capable of executing some pretty general code on the machine.

Comment: You may instead want to make something with Mathematica Online. This doesn't require you to install anything.

Comment: You can turn it into a portable app in a virtual machine if you have another PC.